# I want to convert pdf to image using pdf2image in python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, image, pdf

I want to convert pdf to image using pdf2image in python on Mac OS X.

```
    from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
from pdf2image.exceptions import (
    PDFInfoNotInstalledError,
    PDFPageCountError,
    PDFSyntaxError
)
# define pdf path
# convert pdf to image（1200dpi）
pdf_path = Path(".")
images = convert_from_path(str(pdf_path), 1200)
# save image files one by one
image_dir = Path(".")
for i, page in enumerate(pages):
    file_name = pdf_path.stem + "_{:02d}".format(i + 1) + ".jpeg"
    image_path = image_dir / file_name
    # save JPEG
    page.save(str(image_path), "JPEG")
```

and then I get empty files... 
I cannot understand what is happening.
Any thoughts from anyone??

Comment: `pages` isn't defined anywhere, also, your `pdf_path` of `"."` is odd. should it be like `my_file.pdf` or something?

Comment: true. I forgot to define pages.

Answer (score 1):

Hiro

By using the `pdf2image` library can be used convert `pdf` to `image` like this way,

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('pdf_file', 500) // where 500 is dpi
```

Saving pages in jpeg format

```
for page in pages:
    page.save('out.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

For converting the first page of the PDF and nothing else check this Example,

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('file.pdf', 500)
pages = convert_from_path('file.pdf', 500, single_file=True)
pages[0].save('file.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: If it helps you then you can accepted this answer in future to anyone get trust in this.